# How to execute test in JUnit test for multiple files

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I want to test multiple files using JUnit test in Spring Framework. So far my progress is I can read files from directory using Spring Framework global.properties. My test class reads files from the directory and in @Before I read those files and send one by one to my @Test function to generate test results.

```
@RunWith(MultiThreadedRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class FullCycleTest {


@Before  
public void beforeUploadTest() throws Exception {


    new TestContextManager(getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this); // TestContextManager is responsible for managing Spring TestContext Framework
    this.resourcesTest = new ResourcesTest();   // get instance of ResourceTest class
    this.uploadTest = new UploadandJobTest();
    this.folder = new File(resourcesTest.basePath());
    this.file = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] fileEntry = folder.listFiles();
    this.uploadControllerTest = new UploadControllerTest();
    this.uploadResult = new UploadJSON();

    /******File upload read*****/

    for (int i = 0; i < fileEntry.length; i++) {
        if (fileEntry[i].exists()) { 
            file.add(String.valueOf(fileEntry[i]));
            System.out.println("Testing for file" + file);

        }
    }
}

@Test
public void UploadandJobTest() {

    for (String s : file) {

        uploadTest.uploadAndJobTest(s);
        uploadControllerTest.upload_stl_response(s);
    }
}
```

So in the @Test I can test each file one by one in the test. What I want to do is test all the files concurrently without waiting to finish each file. I know there is TestSuite which can execute all the test inside TestSuite. In my case this is not useful. Is there any way to create @Test programmatically without using any annotation @Test ??Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used Parameterized tests in the past, with good results, and there is this which allows you to use `@RunWith(Parallelized.class)` to make it work.

Here is the example:

```
@RunWith(Parallelized.class)
public class FeatureTest
{
   // same class body as above
}
```

All you need is a simple extension of the Parameterized runner:

```
public class Parallelized extends Parameterized
{

    private static class ThreadPoolScheduler implements RunnerScheduler
    {
        private ExecutorService executor; 

        public ThreadPoolScheduler()
        {
            String threads = System.getProperty("junit.parallel.threads", "16");
            int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(threads);
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        }

        @Override
        public void finished()
        {
            executor.shutdown();
            try
            {
                executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exc)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void schedule(Runnable childStatement)
        {
            executor.submit(childStatement);
        }
    }

    public Parallelized(Class klass) throws Throwable
    {
        super(klass);
        setScheduler(new ThreadPoolScheduler());
    }
}
```

More info here http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2009/12/running-parameterized-junit-tests-in.html